# Disable Directory Listing In Cent OS

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos

Pls I would like to know how to disable directory listing for my Cent O.S server default i.p like 8.8.8.8

Would like to know which of the conf file that I would edit

Is it this file /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf that I would edit

Answer (score 1):

No, welcome.conf isn't that. Read about `IndexIgnore` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexignore and `Options -Indexes` http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options directives.

Answer (score 1):

The 'welcome.conf' file in RHEL derivates is meant as a starting point. You should probably create your own config, more fit for your setup.

Regarding disabling directory index[2], this is a simple google search away:

http://bit.ly/LzSjKu

[2] http://www.techiecorner.com/106/how-to-disable-directory-browsing-using-htaccess-apache-web-server/